# regarding installation of php in apache tomacat 7.0

Tags: php, tomcat

I have installed apache tomacat 7.0 which is unable to compile PHP file . I visited php site "http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php" but i didn't get what to install and how to integrate it in apache tomcat . So,can anyone tell me the whole procedure?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/apache-tomcat-7-0-11-and-php-925305/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this. While it is possible to get PHP to work with Apache Tomcat it is far from an ideal solution. If you want to use PHP then use it with Apache http rather than Apache Tomcat. There are many guides for setting this up - including the manual you quote in your question.